# Changing the Google Maps Marker HTML after a function is ran

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

So I'm trying to figure out a way to change the HTML of Google Maps V3 markers after they have been pulled from the database but before they are pushed up to the array.

When getFishing() is called, I'd like to run convertRate(rate) so that if the rate variable is equal to two or more, it shows a picture which is within the HTML of the Markers themselves.  I've tried putting it in the bindInfoWindow4() and I've tried several places within the getFishing() function with no success.  Has anyone done this before?  Is it possible after the markers have been pushed up to the fishArray?

```
     function getFishing() {
        fishingUrl("XML_Fishing.php", function (data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
                var title = markers[i].getAttribute("title");
                var rate = markers[i].getAttribute("rate");
                var Fishhtml = "<img id='1star' src='images/1star.png' style='visibility:hidden'>";
                var icon = FishingIcon;
                var Fishmark = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    icon: icon.icon
                });
                fishArray.push(Fishmark);
                bindInfoWindow4(Fishmark, map, Fishinfo, Fishhtml);

            }
        });
    }
    function convertRate(rate) {
        if (rate >= 2) {
            document.getElementById("1star").style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }

    function bindInfoWindow4(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you change your click listener to display the HTML saved in a member variable of the marker, you can change it at any time.  If the InfoWindow is open, you may want to close it and reopen it (or update its content in place, but that gets more complicated).

Something like:

```
  function bindInfoWindow4(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      marker.myHtmlContent = html;
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(marker.myHtmlContent);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
  }
```

Then update the content by changing the value in marker.myHtmlContent.  To make it visible, somthing like this:

```
  marker.myHtmlContent = "<img id='1star' src='images/1star.png' style='visibility:visible'>";
```

Comment: can you help me out with how I would go about specifying to change the content for marker.myHtmlContent?  All I know how to do is change content by specifying the 'id' of element Id.  You don't have to give me the exact answer but get me rolling, please.

Comment: would it be something like: marker.myHtmlContent.getElementById("1star").style.visibility='visible';

Comment: This works but I actually took out a bunch of the irrelevant HTML that also goes with the infoWindow (it's not just one picture).  is there a way to just update the visiblity of the one picture of the infoWindow or will I just have to store two full versions of the HTML?

Comment: I got it with   marker.myHtmlContent = html + "<img id='1star' src='images/1star.png' style='visibility:visible'>";

Comment: Thanks again, this wasn't the first time you've helped me and I really appreciate it.