# how to refresh content of already open infowindow of google maps when marker position is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have a google map and markers on it. Markers can move like vehicle tracking.I succeeded moving the markers according to new location data.There is no problem here.When clicking a marker, a infowindow which has location info (lng & ltd) is opened.But If marker move another location while infowindow is open, content(location info) of infowindow dont change.

How to change infowindow's content with new location info while marker moves?

Please help me to overcome the problem?

**creating markers firstly is as follows;**

```
 var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.2312, 36.9041),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        disableDefaultUI: false,
        zoomControl: true
    };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('pnlMap'), mapOptions);
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinateInfo[1].replace(',', '.'), coordinateInfo[0].replace(',', '.'));
                    bounds.extend(latlng);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: '../images/ship_icon.png',
                        store_id: coordinateInfo[3],
                        title: coordinateInfo[2]
                    });
                    markerList.push(marker);

                    (function (marker, coordinateInfo) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                            infoWindow.setContent(
                        '<div id="iw-container">' +
                            '<div class="iw-title">' + coordinateInfo[2] +
                                '<div class="iw-content">' +
                        '<table class="zebra"> <tr> <td><b>Gemi Adı : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfo[2] + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Cihaz ID Numarası : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfo[3] + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Koordinat Bilgileri(X,Y) : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfo[0] + ' - ' + coordinateInfo[1] + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Telefon Numarası : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfo[9] + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Telsiz Numarası : </b></td> <td></td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Hız : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfo[6] + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Gps Zamanı : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfo[10] + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Konum : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfo[11] + '</td> </tr> </table>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>');
                            infoWindow.maxWidth = 380;
                            infoWindow.maxWidth = 380;
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                    })(marker, coordinateInfo);

                    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
                        infoWindow.close();
                    });
```

**updating markers' new position is as follows;**

```
  for (var k = 0; k < coordinateLength - 1; k++) {
                    var coordinateInfoTemp = coordinates[k].split("~");
                    for (var j = 0; j < markerList.length; j++) {
                        var markerTmp = markerList[j];
                        if (markerTmp.store_id === coordinateInfoTemp[3]) {
                            var latlngNew = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinateInfoTemp[1].replace(',', '.'), coordinateInfoTemp[0].replace(',', '.'));
                            markerTmp.setPosition(latlngNew);
                            (function (markerTmp, coordinateInfoTemp) {
                                google.maps.event.addListener(markerTmp, "click", function (e) {
                                    alert(coordinateInfoTemp[10]);
                                    infoWindow.setContent(
                                                            '<div id="iw-container">' +
                                                                '<div class="iw-title">' + coordinateInfoTemp[2] +
                                                                    '<div class="iw-content">' +
                                                            '<table class="zebra"> <tr> <td><b>Gemi Adı : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfoTemp[2] + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Cihaz ID Numarası : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfoTemp[3] + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Koordinat Bilgileri : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfoTemp[0] + ' - ' + coordinateInfoTemp[1] + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Telefon Numarası : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfoTemp[9] + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Telsiz Numarası : </b></td> <td></td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Hız : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfoTemp[6] + '</td> </tr> <tr> <td><b>Gps Zamanı : </b></td> <td>' + coordinateInfoTemp[10] + '</td> </tr> </table>' +
                                                                '</div>' +
                                                            '</div>');
                                    infoWindow.maxWidth = 380;
                                    infoWindow.refresh();
                                });
                            })(markerTmp, coordinateInfoTemp);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution by adding following control, when I clicked a marker I am setting markerTmp.store_id to selectedMarkerStoreId variable;

```
if (selectedMarkerStoreId != null && selectedMarkerStoreId === markerTmp.store_id) {
                                    infoWindow.setContent(markerTmp.htmlContent);
                                }
```

Comment: Add some code to your question that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Based from this [tutorial](http://itpscan.info/examples/google_maps/maps_01a/), you have to close the info window first to be able to refresh its content. See [Modifying content within info-window in google maps api v3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13750844/5995040) and [Changing the Google Maps Marker HTML after a function is ran](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13504662/5995040) about modifying the `infowindow` by modifying the DOM.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot thanks your sharing, but these didn't not help me and present a way to refresh content of "open" infowindow without closing it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you got only one infowindow,then all u need to do is add a listener to refresh the infowindow's content

```
    marker.addListener('click', function () {
        var content = '<p>Lat:'+this.getPosition().lat()+'</p><p>Lng:'+ this.getPosition().lng();
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(yourmap,this);
    });
```

hope it helps.

UPDATE:

```
  for (var k = 0; k < coordinateLength - 1; k++) {
                var coordinateInfoTemp = coordinates[k].split("~");
                for (var j = 0; j < markerList.length; j++) {
                    var markerTmp = markerList[j];
                    if (markerTmp.store_id === coordinateInfoTemp[3]) {
                        var latlngNew = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinateInfoTemp[1].replace(',', '.'), coordinateInfoTemp[0].replace(',', '.'));
                        markerTmp.setPosition(latlngNew);
                        infowindow.setContent(yourcontent);//update here
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks you @RoolearnGear, code what you share runs on click event, But I want to fire infowindow refreshing operation on marker's position change while infowindow is already open. Does your code helps me?

Comment: how about just set the content when u update the marker?

Comment: I have missed this part, I added now.

Comment: don't put the setContent() inside the click event , unless you want to click the marker again to refresh the infowindow

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: i dont figure out what u mean , do u want to bind click event to fresh infowindow?

if not, then remove the click event which is inside your if-statement , and put setContent() after yourmarker.setPosition()

Answer (score 0):

*Putting my findings here for future dev:*

I was trying to update marker data and reflect the updated data on infowindow.

I tried different ways and found simply opening the infowindow reloads the data itself.

so I just triggered a click event on marker and it worked:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click')
```